# Cardinality of ordered n-grams and subsets of those n-grams from a given set

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set T={A,B,C}, I need to know the cardinality of all ordered sequential n-grams and the total cardinality of all subsets of those n-grams.  To be clear, the subsets MUST retain order as they appear in the original set.

1. The ordered sequential n-grams of the set T above are {{A},{B},{C},{A,B},{B,C},{A,B,C}} and its cardinality is **6**.
2. The total cardinality of all subsets for those n-grams is **sum(1,1,1,2,2,3)=10**

So, given set T, what are the formulae for #1 and #2?

Comment: Your "ordered sequential n-grams" appear to be simply "subsets".  Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes!  Some background: I use those terms because I am trying to solve this in the context of a lookup for full-text search.  We have a string and break it into n-grams and then search those.  We need to know the total number tokens that get searched when the number of terms in the query is high, and optimize.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, not exactly. If $ABC$ is a string then the asker considers only nonempty substrings of  $ABC$, namely $A,B,C, AB, BC, $ and $ABC$. The problem statement of course needs better wording.

Comment: @evil - I find it strange that this question was closed, considering the commentary was clearly understood and the question answered.  Please be specific on what further clarity you require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $|T| = n$. Then

1. the number of $n$-symbol sequences is $1$, the number of $(n-1)$-symbol sequences is $2$, $\dots$, the number of $1$-symbol sequences is $n$. Thus the number of all ordered sequential $n$-grams is $1+2+\dots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.
2. The total cardinality of all subsets for those $n$-grams is $$\sum_{k=1}^nk(n-k+1) = (n+1)\sum_{k=1}^nk - \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)^2}{2} - \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

For $n=3$ we have

1. $\frac{3\times 4}{2} = 6$
2. $\frac{3\times 4^2}{2} -\frac{3\times 4 \times 7}{6} = 24 - 14 = 10 $